# Recargar una página con un tag <a>

Tags: php, html

Tengo la siguiente duda:

Digamos que tengo una página en php en esta dirección localhost/mipagina.php y otra que está en localhost/mipagina2.php y necesito poner un tag `<a href="">` que me recargue la misma página poniendo una variable en la url.

Sin embargo ese tag `<a>` está en una "plantilla" de header que es la misma para todas las páginas.

Es decir que si pongo `<a href="localhost/mipagina2.php">` y estoy en la página 2 me la recarga pero si estoy en mipagina1.php no la recarga, si no que me lleva a la 2 y yo quiero que simplemente me recargue la misma pero con una variable en la url.

Edito para explicar mejor lo que quiero hacer, es algo como esto aunque evidentemente esto está mal pero soy muy novato en tema de jquery y esas cosas...

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">Añadir parametro par=2 en la url</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<?php $_GET['par'] = '2';?>";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

Puede usar una url relativa, tal que así:

```
 <a href=".">Recargar</a>
```

Y no necesitas ningún tipo de lógica en el servidor para generarlo.
No obstante, para hacerlo mediante PHP, podrías usar el siguiente código:

```
 $pagina_actual = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Esto sin embargo tiene el inconveniente de que el cliente puede modificar el valor de ambas variables a su antojo, provocando resultados no esperados.

Existe la posibilidad de hacerlo mediante javascript:

```
 <a href="javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href">Recargar</a>
```

La ventaja de esta última es que en caso de que la URL contenga parámetros, los mantiene.

Para generarla desde PHP, manteniendo los parámetros enviados por get, podrías hacer algo así:

```
 <?php
 // Construir la base de nuestra url
 $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]?" . http_build_query($_GET);

 // Comprobar si el parámetro par viene en la url
 if (!isset($_GET['par']) || trim($_GET['par']) == '') {
     $url .= '&par=2';
 }
 ?>
 <a href="<?=$url?>">Recargar</a>
```

Este código es solo a efectos de muestra, ya que puede ser altamente optimizado en términos de rendimiento y seguridad, pero así te harás una idea clara de cómo hacerlo.

Comment: NEcesito que mantenga los parametros pero también necesito que añada uno más al recargar, pero si añade uno más por ejemplo par=2 entonces cuando vuelva a darle al botón y el parametro par ya está puesto que no lo añada otra vez, simplemente que cambie su valor por otro...

Comment: @PavloB. He actualizado la respuesta, espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que la mejor opción es con:

```
window.location.reload(true)
```

usándolo de esta forma:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.reload(true)">
```

Ejemplo

```js
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = Date();
```

```html
<html>
<body bgcolor="aqua">

<a title="Reload!" href="#" onclick="window.location.reload(true)">Reload !</a>
 
<p id="time"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Al menos en Chrome, `location` tiene una propiedad `search` que permite hacer exactamente lo que necesitas:

```
<a href="#" onclick="location.search='?foo=bar'">Reload</a>
```

De esta manera recargas la página agregando la variable `foo` con el valor `bar` al URL. Desconozco si funciona en otros navegadores.

Aquí un ejemplo completo para los navegadores que no soporten la propiedad `search` y para los casos donde ya existan parámetros previos:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script>
         function refresh() {
            var url = location.href.replace(/#$/, '');
            if (/\?/.test(url)) {
               var partes = url.split('?');
               var params = partes[1].split('&');
               var paramsfinal = [];
               for (var i in params) {
                  if (!params[i].startsWith('foo=')) {
                     paramsfinal.push(params[i]);
                  }
               }
               paramsfinal.push('foo=bar');
               location.href = partes[0] +'?' +paramsfinal.join('&'); 
            } else {
               location.href = url +'?foo=bar';
            }
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>foo es <?php echo isset($_GET['foo']) ? $_GET['foo'] : '(vacío)'; ?></p>
      <a href="#" onclick="refresh()">Recargar</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No funciona con otros navegadores?

Comment: mantiene los otros parametros?

Comment: Desconozco si funciona con otros navegadores. De no ser así deberías escribir alguna función que tome el `href` y lo modifique a tú necesidad. NO mantiene los otros parámetros, reemplaza la cadena entera.

Comment: Modifiqué la respuesta para que sirva en esos casos.

Comment: Lo he copiado tal cual y no me unciona, no recarga la página, simplemente añade una almohadilla "#" en la url y no hace nada más.

Comment: Modifiqué la respuesta para que elimine el signo `#` al final.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar la función [basename()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.basename.php) de PHP para obtener el nombre del archivo y apuntar tu enlace a ese archivo de acuerdo a donde estes en ese momento, algo así:

```
<?php
  echo '<a href="'.basename(__FILE__).'">Recargar</a>'; 
?>
```

O tambien podrias usar javascript para realizar la recarga.

Comment: Esto me sirve hasta cierto punto, pero necesito que además de recargar como hace esa función me conserve los parametros que ya tengo en la url...

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción que no se ha mencionado, es simplemente con [$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php#refsect1-reserved.variables.server-indices):

```
<a href="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">Recargar</a>
```

**Info de seguridad:**

Al insertar cualquier variable en HTML (como en este caso de la URL) y que pueda ser modificado de un usuario, es altamente recomendado que uses la función [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars.php), se evita por ejemplo un ataque [Cross-Site-Scripting (XSS)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Answer (score 0):

Otra opcion similar es

```
location.reload();
```

Tambien puede ser:

```
location.reload(true);
```

La diferencia es que al ponerle **true** te descarga la pagina nuevamente desde el servidor, esto es principalmente util en IE ya que en algunas versiones al ocupar esto no refrescaba la pagina.